# How to set receiver sensitivity in Veins-5.x?

Tags: omnet++, veins

In Veins-4.x, setting the receiver sensitivity is done through this line

```
*.**.nic.phy80211p.sensitivity = -89dBm
```

However, this parameter disappeared in Veins-5.x.
Is there a replacement in the current version of Veins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `minPowerLevel` gives the minimum receive power that is needed to even attempt decoding a frame.

Here is an example:

```
*.**.nic.phy80211p.minPowerLevel = -110dBm
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Where can I find a log for these changes?
Moreover, what is the different between .minPowerLevel and .ccaThreshold?

Comment: `minPowerLevel` specifies the value above which at least frames are tried to be decoded.
`ccaThreshold` specifies the powerlevel at which the channel is considered busy.

Comment: What is the relation between these values? which one should be bigger than the other?